# How to import data from a text file and calculate calculations on it

Tags: python

Hi hope all is well with everyone.

I have created a simple python calculator which calculates inputs from a user, however the second stage of my project is to allow the user to enter a file(more details below to avoid repetition):

"read all of the equations from a new txt file (the user should add the name of the txt file as an input) and print out all of the equations together with the results. Use defensive coding to ensure that the program does not crash if the file does not exist and that the user is prompted again to enter the name of the file."

I am able to open up and split the user entered file however I am not sure how to run my maths calculator function on it, and then get it to print in an output file. Second problem I am running into is, I am unable to defensive code the file so that if it does not exist then it requests the user to reenter the name of the file. So in short my code crashes everytime it is a non existing file instead of re requesting the user to enter a name.

Below is the code i have managed to write:

```
#user inputs if they would like to use a a text file to run calculations

choice2 = input("Would you like to use your own file for calculations or enter a number\nFile - f\nNumber - n?:").lower()

if choice2 == 'f':
    questionsfile = input("Please enter the name of the file:")
    mathsfile = open(questionsfile +".txt",'r')

file = None
    try:
        file = open(mathsfile,'r')
        
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        print("The file that you are trying to open does not exist")
        print(error)
    finally:
        if file is not None:
            file.close()
```

Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: Can you explain what the file might look like and what the expected user input might be?

Comment: the text file format would be like: 'maths.txt' 1+2, or even 1 + 2

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop wherein you prompt the user to input either a formula or the name of a file (that contains multiple formulae). You also need a way to break out of that loop. Then you need to prompt for input based on the user's choice at the first step.

The *operator* module is particularly useful for this.

Try this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
from re import compile

OMAP = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}

pattern = compile(r'^(\d+\.*\d*)\s*(.)\s*(\d+\.*\d*)$')

print('A Python calculator\n')
print('You can enter simple formulae as X op Y where X and Y are numbers (integer or floating point) and op is one of +, -, *, /')
print('You can optionally provide the name of a file that may contain multiple lines in the same format')

def calculate(expr):
    try:
        x, o, y = pattern.match(expr).groups()
        if op := OMAP.get(o):
            print(f'{expr} = {op(float(x), float(y))}')
        else:
            print(f'Unknown operator {o}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Unable to process "{expr}" due to {e}')

while True:
    response = input('\n1) User entered formula 2) filename 3) End program: ')
    match response:
        case '1':
            expr = input('Enter formula: ')
            calculate(expr)
        case '2':
            filename = input('Enter filename: ')
            try:
                with open(filename) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                        calculate(line.strip())
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        case '3':
            break
        case _:
            print('Invalid option\a')
```